# create an increasing sequence number per year in c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, numbers, sequence

Is there a way to create a sequence number per year as student ID
and it should contains year + sequence number
like this : 20150001 / 20160001

is it possible to be in code behind..

any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var sequence = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year * 10000 + 1, 500);` for *500* students and *current* year?

Comment: First I'll read the last studentID from table, if last record for example = 20150020 then the next ID will be: 201500021..

Comment: Dont glue 2 independent pieces of information together like that for an ID, it is bad design.  Any DB worthy of the name can produce an abstract autoincrement ID.  If you are going to ever get the students enrolled in year YYYY, the way to do that is **not** to look at *part* of the ID

Comment: maybe to you is kind of stupid idea but I am not professional in coding in my opinion the students keep register semester by semester so, I can find the students how registered in 2014 or 2015 by reading the ID and find out the student level, also know how many students with ID start 2015.. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an easy code:

```
Function GetID() As Long
    Dim vyear As Integer = 2015
    Dim vsno As Long
    cmd1.Connection = con1
    VSQL = "select max(ID) as vID from Table"
    cmd1.CommandText = VSQL
    cmd1.Connection = conOra
    rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader
    rdr1.Read()
    If rdr1.HasRows Then
        If TypeName(rdr1!vID) <> "DBNull" Then
            vsno = rdr1!vID + 1
            GetID = vyear & vsno
        Else
            GetID = vyear & "0001"
        End If
    End If
    rdr1.Close()
    con1.close()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the below..

```
Dim SequenceNo as String = 'whatever you want the start number to be
Dim Year as String = 'This would be set to the year
Dim RequiredOutput as String = 'this would be set to the number of students you have
Dim StudentID as New List(Of String)

Do Until SequenceNo > RequiredOutput 
   StudentID.Add(Year & SequenceNo)
   SequenceNo += 1
loop
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to start sequence number with 4 digits = 0001 and also I need the year to be get from the system.

Comment: If your using String variables, you would just set string variable to 0001 eg. `Dim SequenceNo as String = "0001"`

Comment: With the year you would put something like eg. `Dim CurrentYear as DateTime = Date.Today.Year` and then set `Dim Year as String = CurrentYear.ToString `

Comment: Thanks again, one more think instead of loop can I select max(StudentID) from the table to get the next student ID because I do not know the number of students will register.

Comment: Im confused what you are asking for? Could you not just set the RequiredOutput  to be the maximum students from your table?

Comment: I am putting this code before inserting into a table, so I have to get last student id and increase 1 digit for next student ID

Comment: So all you need to do is, get the last studentID then get the sequence number from it (the last 4 digits) and set that as your Starting sequence number after adding 1 to it .

Comment: Yes that exactly what I need thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create method to Generate next sequence number which can take year (or admission date) and student id something like below.

```
  private static string GenerateNextSequence(DateTime addmissionDate, int studentNumber, int maxPad = 4) {
        var studentNumberString = studentNumber.ToString();
        return
            string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", addmissionDate.Year,
                (new StringBuilder()).Append('0', maxPad - studentNumberString.Length), studentNumberString);

    }
```

maxPad in above method is maximum number of students length(if max students is 9999, then length is 4)